# Copy from GpuMat to Texture2D is too slow

Tags: c++, opencv

I've implemented a copy using "cv::ogl::Texture2D::copyTo()" function. I am passing to the copyTo a cv::cuda::GpuMat. This is working well and is based on an example from the following post:

[Is it possible to bind a OpenCV GpuMat as an OpenGL texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086519/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-opencv-gpumat-as-an-opengl-texture/18106590#18106590)

The issue that I'm having is that it takes about 30ms to complete the copy, whereas if I first download my *GpuMat* to a *cv::Mat m* and then use *opengl's*

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, The_GL_Data_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m.data);`

meaning that when I do the round trip of the data via the CPU/Host memory it only takes ~13ms.

**My Question is**:
How can I accelerate the data transfer between cv::cuda and opengl? Anywhere I've looked I couldn't find a discussion on the performance of interoperability between opengl and cv::cuda.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have access to the cuda pointers? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947099/sharing-texture-between-opengl-and-cuda

Comment: I'm not sure if I have access to the cuda pointers, I assume that I can include the cuda headers and create that access? Never done that before. What I do have is a GpuMat m_gpu; that was already initialized and processed in another thread, now I'm in the OpenGL thread, I've created Texture2D tex; and did a copy tex.copyFrom(m_gpu); and tex.bind(); Do you believe that I need to replace those lines with direct cuda pointers?